# TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

`this.dispatcher[guildID] = this.connection[guildID].play(ytdl(Queue[msg.guild.id][playing[msg.guild.id]]),{highWaterMark: 1<<25 });`

When I use this code on Discord Js and execute it,it Will Show this Error Code

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined**

Before that, I have used the following code:
`if(playing[msg.guild.id] == undefined)setTimeout(function(){music.Musicplay(msg,msg.guild.id);},500);`

Answer (score 0):

A bit more information would be extremely helpful as it's hard to determine what is going on in your small snippet of code, but it seems as though you're trying to play a file through a discord voice channel.

Because we can't see more of your JavaScript, we can't determine much, but it is possible that you never defined the 'play' veriable? Thats what the error implies.

Answer (score 0):

This is My AddMusic And PlayMusic Code

```
play(msg)
    {
        if (this.connection[msg.guild.id] == undefined)
        {
            this.join(msg);
        }
        //In the string, leave the URL!
        const musicURL = msg.content.replace(`${prefix}play `,'');
        if(Queue[msg.guild.id] == undefined)
            {
                Queue[msg.guild.id] = [musicURL];
            }
        else
            {
                Queue[msg.guild.id][Queue[msg.guild.id].length] = musicURL;
            }
        
            getInfo(musicURL).then(info => {
                const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Added: "+info.items[0].title)
                .setURL(musicURL)
                .setColor('#2fffff')
                msg.channel.send(Embed);
            });
        
            ytdl.getInfo(musicURL,function(err,info)
            {
                if(err)
                    {
                        const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle("The song has been added, but the title information cannot be obtained!")
                        .setURL(musicURL)
                        .setColor('#FF0000')
                        msg.channel.send(Embed);
                    }
                else
                    {
                        const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle("Added: "+info.videoDetails.title)
                        .setURL(musicURL)
                        .setColor('#2fffff')
                        msg.channel.send(Embed);
                    }
            })
        console.log(msg.guild.id);
        console.log(Queue[msg.guild.id]);
        
        if(playing[msg.guild.id] == 0)
            {
                if(Queue[msg.guild.id].length != 0)
                   {
                        playing[msg.guild.id] = Queue[msg.guild.id].length-1;
                   }
                setTimeout(function(){music.Musicplay(msg,msg.guild.id);},500);
            }
        if(playing[msg.guild.id] == undefined)
            setTimeout(function(){music.Musicplay(msg,msg.guild.id);},500);
    }
    
    Musicplay(msg,guildID)
    {
        if(playing[msg.guild.id] == undefined)
            {
                playing[msg.guild.id] = 0;
            }
        
        ytdl.getInfo(Queue[guildID][playing[guildID]],function(info)
        {
            msg.channel.send('Currently playing:'+ Queue[guildID][playing[guildID]]);
        });
        
        console.log(Queue[guildID][playing[guildID]]);
        this.dispatcher[guildID] = this.connection[guildID].play(ytdl(Queue[msg.guild.id][playing[msg.guild.id]]),{highWaterMark: 1<<25 });
        this.dispatcher[guildID].on('finish', () =>
        {
            if(Queue[msg.guild.id].length <= playing[msg.guild.id])
                {
                    playing[msg.guild.id] += 1;
                    this.Musicplay(msg);
                }
            else
                {
                    playing[msg.guild.id] = 0;
                }
            
        });
    }
```

This Is Error Code

```
this.dispatcher[guildID] = this.connection[guildID].play(ytdl(Queue[msg.guild.id][playing[msg.guild.id]]),{highWaterMark: 1<<25 });
```